# I can't seem to get the FancyBox class to link to a picture

Tags: html

I am currently experimenting with FancyBox for the first time and have followed many tutorials but for some reason, the fancybox class doesn't apply to the image that I want to use it for. I know I need to edit my image names.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<body class="gallery">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
</head>
</br>
  <title>TekMillion - Gallery</title>

<p style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/TEKMILL%20logo%20RESIZE.png" alt="Tekmill Logo" width="839" height="322"></center></p>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

<HR>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>  
  <li><a href="merchandise.html">Shop</a></li>               
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="albums.html">Albums</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<HR>

<div class="container">
</br>
<span class="textformat1"><center><b>Gallery</b></span></center>


<a class="fancybox" href="images/pic1fullsize.jpg"><img src="images/1932078_1068348593195968_1861115484_n.jpg" alt="1932078_1068348593195968_1861115484_n" width="250" height="150"></a>






<br/>
</center>
</div>
</div>
<hr>

<img src="images/stayconnected.png" align="left" alt="stayconnected" width="200" height="43" style="padding-top:4px;"></center>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/tekmill/"><img src="images/Instagram.png" align="middle" alt="Instagram" width="50" height="50"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/TekMillMusic"><img src="images/facebook%20logo.png" align="middle" alt="facebook%20logo" width="50" height="50"></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/TekMillMusic"><img src="images/youtube%20logo.png" align="middle" alt="youtube%20logo" width="50" height="50"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/tekmill"><img src="images/Twitter.png" align="middle" alt="Twitter" width="50" height="50"></a>
</br>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 });
 
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting both your JQuery Library and Fancybox JS links to the very end of your html file (right before the </body> tag. Make sure that the JQ Library comes first and then at the very end the fancybox.js. This solved a similar problem for me a while ago, give it a try.

Comment: You missed closing the `<script>` tag

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the problem, any other solutions ?